# Javascript css marginTop transition not triggering with animation

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I have a navigation bar with the id of `#navigation`, trough css the id has its margins set to -100 so it is not visible when the page loads, I then added a onLoad listener to the id. Then I wrote some js to transition the id back to be visible. The issue is that the JS does not transition the id back, it simply shows it when the page loads but there is no animation of the id transitioning back down.

**HTML**

```
<body onLoad="navBack()">
<section id="navigation">
  <nav>
      <ul id="navList">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
</body>
```

**Here is the JS**

```
function navBack(){
   var element = document.getElementById('navigation');
   element.style.transition = "marginTop 6.0s linear 6.0s";
   element.style.marginTop = "10px";
     }
```

Comment: can you please provide us a fiddle from http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sure, here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/w9Cwx/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w9Cwx/1/ is this your expected behavior

Comment: That's the result Im currently getting, The navbar just shows up with 10px margin on top. My goal is to get to move from -100px down to 10px

Answer (score 0):

```
element.style.transition = "margin-top 6.0s linear";
```

`margin-top` is the css property not `marginTop`

http://jsfiddle.net/w9Cwx/11/

http://jsfiddle.net/w9Cwx/13/